Need help in understanding an example illustrating Quotient spaces in the linear algebraic context
I found the following problem used as an example to introduce quotient spaces in linear algebra. But quite confused as to how equation (2) is obtained? Appreciate any help.
Example 1. $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$, $W$ is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  Since $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \text{ span } \mathbb{R}^3, \text{ we can choose } \overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}} \text{ and } \overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}} \text{ as a basis for the two-dimensional quotient space } V/W.
$$
Now, for example,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 3 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - 2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} ->eq(1)
$$
so
$$
\overline{\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}} = -2 \overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}} + \overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}} -> eq(2)
$$
In a similar manner we can express the equivalence class of any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a linear combination of $\overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}}$ and $\overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}}$.
Notice, incidentally, that $\overline{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}}$ and $\overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}}$ would not serve as a basis for $V/W$. Because their sum is an element of $W$, they are not linearly independent elements of $V/W$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \text{ so } \overline{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}} + \overline{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}} = \overline{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}} = \overline{0}.
$$
Edit: I'm new to this level of math abstraction and trying to understand the steps in between eq-(1) and eq-(2). The overlines seem to indicate that the elements in eq-(2) are cosets. Also, I understand the point in the comments about (1,1,0) being treated as zero in V/W. But I believe that the equality in eq(2) is a different kind of equality (a coset equality?) than a simple vector equality. If so, should there be some sort of a qualifier stating that? This is the issue on which I was hoping to get some help. I've tried to follow all the guidelines in posting the question but I sense a rush to close it, not sure what was missing on my part.

$(2)$ follows directly from $(1)$, because by definition $\overline{3\cdot (1,1,0)}=\overline{(0,0,0)}$ in the quotient space.

Don't understand the down votes and close votes. Perfectly clear question to me, very reasonable one a student can have learning this for the first time.

As said by YiFan Tey, this student has spent time to explain in a clear way, moreover with a well "Latexified" text, what is his/her question. For me, somebody who desires to close such a question is a person who hasn't any contact with students, nor remember the time they were students. Systematic closing before having the time to interact with the person who has asked the question should be exceptional.

If $v_1,v_2\in\Bbb R^3$, then$$\overline{v_1}=\overline{v_2}\iff v_1-v_2\in W.$$So,\begin{align}\overline{\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}}&=\overline{-2\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}}\\&=\overline{-2\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}}+\overline{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}}\\&=-2\overline{\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}}+\overline{\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}}.\end{align}
